# Assets duplicate on front end

Tags: ee2, assets, stash

Weird one, front end showing duplicates of assets but only sometimes on some entries and always disappears after saving the entry.

It appears to be random, that is to say with 300+ products we only notice it when we visit the page it occurs on.

**Here's the asset field in the CP**
[image]

**Here's the front End** (Code view shows it's properly there)
[image]

**Save the entry and this is the front end after refresh**
[image]

I have stash in play here and thought it might be a cache issue, so I forced the cache `{exp:stash:flush_cache}` to no avail.

Using EE2.5.5 with Assets 2.03 + Stash 2.3.6

Here's a snippet of the code in use:

```
{exp:stash:set parse_tags="yes" trim="yes" parse_conditionals="yes" no_results_prefix="my_prefix"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="{stash:TheChan}" url_title="{segment_3}" require_entry="yes"}
{stash:symbols}
        {{stash:prefix}_symbols}
            <li><img src="{url}" alt="{alt_text}" title="{title}" /></li>
        {/{stash:prefix}_symbols}
    {/stash:symbols}
… a whole heap of captured 'stashes'
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

I've searched P&T and whilst this phenomena is not unheard of, it was apparently sorted back in assets 1.4

**UPDATED/SIMPLIFIED TEMPLATE**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="filler-metals" url_title="{segment_3}" require_entry="yes"}
<div class="container body">

            {fm_symbols}
                <li><img src="{url}" alt="{alt_text}" title="{title}" /></li>
            {/fm_symbols}

</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: You definitely need to take Stash completely out of the picture to eliminate that as the cause. Try your code with a standard Channel Entries tag in a blank template first.

Comment: Stash removed and "pain persists" :(

Comment: Can you post that plain Channel Entries + Assets field code?

Comment: Simplified template added

Comment: Hey Stuart -I'd like to login to your site and have a look.  Any chance you could email support@pixelandtonic.com with a link to this thread and some Superadmin details? Thank you!

Comment: Did you work out what was happening? I'm seeing this with EE 2.9.2 and Assets 2.5.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The issue sort of dissapeared during build. Had to be some sort of cache issue I suspect.