# Double up of Assets File Upload preferences within Assets addon

Tags: add-on, assets, focus-lab-master-config

We've just updated to the latest version of Assets v2.0.4 and have noticed that there's two of every upload preference displaying in the side column. We're using the Focus Lab Config for this site and have the preferences set in the config.master.php similar to the following:

```
    1 => array(
        'name'        => 'Files - Documents',
        'server_path' => $media_path . '/files/documents/',
        'url'         => $media_url  . '/files/documents/'
    )
```

There looks to be two possible problems, the first being that changing something in the config, doesn't reflect the change in Assets, and the problem of the subject matter whereby we see two of each File Upload preference. The above example would have entries in the side column for:

```
Files - Documents
documents
```

The proper name, and the name of the directory.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Thought I would update showing what's going on in my instance. First of all here's my upload preferences so you can see they're pretty normal beasts.

[image: Screenshot showing File Upload Preferences are normal]

[image: Example of what the Images: General paths look like when viewed - ie. not relative]

Now this is the output from Assets (v2.0.5) at time of capture.

[image: Assets upload listing - showing double up of upload folders]

Note that I have an 'All Media' upload preference so that it can be set within WYGWAM as it only allows for a single upload location. The dated folders at the top of the Asset upload point listing are actually subfolders of the Files: Board Documents pref.

Comment: Glad its not just me. Have P&T looking into it. http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5515/assets-duplciate-on-front-end

Comment: For me this is in the backend when using th Assets file manager.

Comment: Brendan, can you try updating to 2.0.5 and see if that helps? If not, it may be time for me to have a look directly.  Thank you!

Comment: Brendan, can you try adding the assets_cp_path to your config.php? That is needed if you're using relative paths.  Thank you!

Comment: I will give that a go, but be aware that the file upload prefs in the Focus Lab config actually resolve to full working paths, not relative. The look relative in the config, but $media_path is a variable that does have the full path. I think we may have solved it on our end though by flushing all the rows in the 'exp_assets_folders' table and doing another Update Index. Problem now we see is after the index it's saying what it looks like all references should be deleted from the DB. Read somewhere this could just be the OCD nature of Assets 2 (BK's words).

Comment: OK, I have done the following:

1) Removed all rows from the 'exp_assets_folders' table.
2) Reindexed all File Upload prefs in Assets using the 'Update Indexes' function.
3) All 'references' to files that Assets provided after updating the indexes I deleted.

This resulted in all existing Asset file references in entries being lost across the website. So clearly there's something else that completely hinky about this. Note that this was previously on Assets v1.2.2 and we moved from DB based file upload prefs to Focus Lab config.

Comment: Have added an example of the $media_path variable being output in EE File Upload preference server path field to the original post.

Comment: BTW, if I leave out the step about deleting the referenced files that Assets thinks are broken, everything seems to work as expected.

Comment: I've just checked the fieldtype settings on a couple of Assets fields (and Matrix columns) and they no longer have the Upload Preference checked. Sounds similar to the other thread here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5680/full-path-seems-incorrect-after-update-to-2-0-4

Comment: Hey Brendan,
Is it possible to get FTP and CP access to take a look at this? If so, please send them to support@pixelandtonic.com and reference this question, so I know what's up.

Comment: Sorry, this is all being done locally at the moment. I'm going to try rolling back to a previous very of the Assets tables and give it another go at the upgrade from 1.x to 2.0.5 and see how that goes. Keep you posted.

Comment: Andris, see my solution below on how we managed to get around the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like we ran into this problem as the first version of Assets that was released didn't honour the settings in our config.master.php for the upload preferences array. This was fixed in Assets v2.0.2 but we had already run the update on the production database (yeah, Rookie mistake) so this is what I did to rectify.

1. I exported the 'exp_assets' and 'exp_assets_entries' table from
   a pre Assets v2.x backup.
2. For good measure I went into each of the 'Content > Files > File
   Upload Preferences' and hit the update button to make sure the paths
   etc are saved into the database as well as still in the config and
   they match.
3. I dropped all the Assets v2 tables from the active database that has
   the messed up tables including 'exp_assets_files',
   'exp_assets_folders', 'exp_assets_index_data',
   'exp_assets_selections' and 'exp_assets_sources'.
4. Imported the old Assets v1x from the old backup that I
   exported in step 1 - 'exp_assets' and 'exp_assets_entries' into the
   active database.
5. Changed the version number for Assets back to v1.1.5 in
   'exp_extentions', 'exp_fieldtypes' and 'exp_modules' within the
   active database. This triggers Assets to run the update process on
   the database tables and do all its work.
6. From the EE CP, go to 'Add-ons > Modules' and click on the 'Assets'
   module - you should be presented with a warning about backing up the
   database prior to running the v2.x update. Make sure you update the
   database prior, then click on the 'Update' button. It will go and do
   its thing and you should be presented back to Assets with all the
   correct upload points presented in the left column.

Confirm the Upload Preference selection has been retained by checking an Assets custom field's settings, ie. it should be checked as it was previous to the update. Also double check the front end and be sure images are rendering, and finally edit an entry and just update it to make sure the Assets fields are sticking with the original images and not disappearing.

You can also now run your 'Update Index' inside Assets and there shouldn't be any references (or at least very little) that will appear that are suggested to be deleted (in this case I ran an update index on one and it was clean.